# How can i target a select statement option to display a certain div in another page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Now any drop down list i click takes me to the same page. I want each drop-down option to open different pages in my project. Please help.

Here is my php page that holds the drop-down list

```
      <section class="main">
           <div class="fleft">
               <select id="cd-dropdown" class="cd-select">
                   <option value="-1" selected>My Result</option>
                   <option value="1">Unofficial Transcript</option>
                   <option value="2">Request Official Transcript</option> 
               </select>
           </div>
      </section>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.dropdown.js</script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="js/animation.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="js/getData.js"></script>
```

Here is my getData.js

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
 $('#cd-dropdown').change(function () {
     var dropval = $(this).val();
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: 'includes/process_ajax.php',
         data: {
             dropdown: dropval

         },
         dataType: 'html'

     }).done(function (data) {
         $('#page1').html(data);
     });
 });
 });
```

Here is my process_ajax.php file

```
<?php
$change_password= 'You clicked me!';
switch ($_POST['dropdown'] != '1' ) {
case "change":
    echo $change_password;
    break;
default:
    echo "Its not working!";
}
?>
```

Comment: Use the HTML target='_self / _blank' property.

Comment: for each options?

Comment: That is up to you.

Comment: You're missing the `">` after `src="js/jquery.dropdown.js`

Comment: What do you mean by open different pages? The PHP script returns different data depending on the dropdown value, isn't that enough?

Comment: but for my case it returns the same data for all drop-down values i click on

Comment: all drop down list opens my process_ajax.php file but is there a way to get each value to return different data in my php file?

Answer (score 0):

You're using `switch` incorrectly. `$_POST['dropdown'] != '1'` will always be either `true` or `false`. This will never be equal to `"change"`, so that case will not be matched, and it will always go to the `default:` case.

It should be:

```
switch($_POST['dropdown']) {
case '1':
    echo "Here is your unofficial transcript";
    break;
case '2':
    echo "Your request for an official transcript has been received"
    break;
default:
    echo "You need to select something";
}
```

The `case` expressions have to match the `value` attributes in the dropdown options.

Comment: Did as you said sir, but it goes to the default case on click on any drop-down list

Comment: What do you mean by "any drop-down list"? This is only designed to work with the specific drop-down that you show in the question. The values have to be `1` and `2`. It looks like your question is mixing up different dropdowns, since your script talks about changing passwords, not returning transcripts.

Comment: i have a list on my nav bar that  loads a new drop down list on another div depending on the one i clcik on. For instance in my first php file if i select the already selected with the _-1_  value in other to change the content am viewing and open another content it doesn't work instead any option i select opens the same content. My goal is to load different contents depending on the option i select in the drop down list

Comment: I'm having a hard time picturing what you're doing, you need to update the question to show the code.

Comment: Sir do you have an email where i can send you a recorded step of what i am trying to achieve?

Comment: Sorry, we don't do private consultations here. The purpose of SO is to create a public resource with questions and solutions. So you need to explain what you're trying to do clearly in the question.